# SSL Error when running pip search in python 2.7.9

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, pip

When I run `pip search circus` - i get the following SSL error:

```
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:490: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I read some articles saying something about adding the site to cacerts.txt, but i do not know what site i need to add, nor where the cacerts.txt file resides.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
pip --cert cacert.pem search circus
```